# How to use awk to only print matches that have the minimum value at a certain field?

Tags: awk, minimum

I am trying to parse some results given by HMMER and in the tblout file I was able to isolate the matches I want.

Nonetheless, the same value is being repeated several times if it matches to just one profile.

For example, this is one read is repeated 3 times:

```
SRR6033660.161030 FAM007172 4e-15 4.2e-15 63.4 63.4
SRR6033660.1458607 FAM019859 2.5e-12 2.7e-12 55.0 54.9
SRR6033660.1458607 FAM015326 4e-14 4.2e-14 58.8 58.7
SRR6033660.1458607 FAM000764 7.5e-25 8.1e-25 94.6 94.5
```

It matches to 3 families, nonetheless I just want to select the row which has the lowest e-values (3rd and 4th columns)

How can I write an awk command that gives me this output?

```
SRR6033660.161030 FAM007172 4e-15 4.2e-15 63.4 63.4
SRR6033660.1458607 FAM000764 7.5e-25 8.1e-25 94.6 94.5
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want if you have rows A and B with A1==B1 where A3>B3 but B4>A4?

Comment: [edit] your question to show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

choosing the min with respect to two fields will not work in general, here I propose a linear combination where you can set the weight.

```
$ awk -v a=0.5 '{c=a*$3+(1-a)*$4}
        !($1 in min) || c<min[$1]{min[$1]=c; minLine[$1]=$0}
         END{for(k in minLine) print minLine[k]}' file | column -t

SRR6033660.1458607  FAM000764  7.5e-25  8.1e-25  94.6  94.5
SRR6033660.161030   FAM007172  4e-15    4.2e-15  63.4  63.4
```

due to hashing, the order of records is not preserved. You can add a sequence number and sort based on that afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

This sums up `$3` and `$4` and the one with smallest sum *has the lowest e-values* (in the absence of a better definition):

```
$ awk '
# $3+$4==s[$1] {            # this commented out part appends records when
#    r[$1]=r[$1] ORS $0     # the sum of $3+$4 is equally small with the 
# }                         # smallest so far
$3+$4<s[$1] || s[$1]=="" {  # if the sum of $3+$4 is the smallest or first
    s[$1]=$3+$4             # store the sum
    r[$1]=$0                # and record
}
END {                       # after all records are processed
    for(i in r)             # loop thru stored records
        print r[i]          # and output them
}' file
SRR6033660.1458607 FAM000764 7.5e-25 8.1e-25 94.6 94.5
SRR6033660.161030 FAM007172 4e-15 4.2e-15 63.4 63.4
```

If you uncomment the first block, the script will output all the records with the smallest `$3+$4`, for example: `awk {script} file file` would output:

```
SRR6033660.1458607 FAM000764 7.5e-25 8.1e-25 94.6 94.5
SRR6033660.1458607 FAM000764 7.5e-25 8.1e-25 94.6 94.5
SRR6033660.161030 FAM007172 4e-15 4.2e-15 63.4 63.4
SRR6033660.161030 FAM007172 4e-15 4.2e-15 63.4 63.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Other people have provided pure awk solutions. Note that they involve loading virtually the entire contents of the data into memory. This is problematic in the general case.

It turns out that sort (specifically the GNU coreutils version, not sure about others) is clever enough to make use of temporary files when dealing with large amounts of data. It can also compare numbers specified in floating-point.

So:

```
LC_NUMERIC=C sort <TBLOUT -k1 -k3g -k4g | awk 't!=$1{t=$1;print}'
```

- first, sort input so that lines are grouped by first column and then ordered numericallg by column 3 and 4
- `LC_NUMERIC=C` ensures we sort properly in locales where numbers are written 1.234,56, for example, rather than 1,234.56
- we can switch around `-k3g` and `-k4g` if 4th column is more important
- no easy way to combine/weight columns 3 and 4 (but we could preprocess each line to produce a new column - perhaps pipe through another awk before the sort)
- pipe result into awk - only print lines where first column has changed